# Place equally grouped members into same buckets

Tags: python, algorithm

I am looking for an optimal algorithm to to the following

I have a list of groups like so

```
groups = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'A', 'E'],
    ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    ['X', 'A', 'W'],
    ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
]
```

I want to put them into buckets where, if there is no bucket, create a new bucket.

For each group like the first one `[A, B, C]` put them into the first bucket. All members of that group belong to the bucket. Now the next group `[D,A,E]` there is at least 1 member which is in bucket 1. This means all members from that group belong to bucket 1.
The next one `[X,Y,Z]` has no members in any bucket. This means create a new bucket and store the members there. Now the next one `[X,A,W]` has a member in bucket 1 and bucket 2. this means bucket 1 and bucket 2 are the same and needs to be merged.

For this example I should have 2 buckets. What would be an efficient way to do it if there is thousands of groups and each group could have hundreds of entries in similar length

Comment: Your post could be improved by including the attempts you have made, so far. Interestingly, I got a notice that told me I am not allowed to ask what you have tried. However stating that you should include what you have tried produces no such message. It also told me to just downvote you and move on. I don't take orders from pink boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by thinking of it as a graph problem. This is essentially asking for connected components of a graph.

The idea is that every element in each group becomes a node, de-duplicating nodes which have the same string. Also, every group becomes a node. Then, in each group, draw a edge from each group to every element that group contains.

[image: graphs]

Then, you group the graph into connected components, which are a set of nodes which are linked to each other by edges.

Code:

```py
import networkx as nx


groups = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'A', 'E'],
    ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    ['X', 'A', 'W'],
    ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
]


def groups_to_graph(groups):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for i, group in enumerate(groups):
        group_name = f"b{i}"
        G.add_node(group_name)
        G.add_nodes_from(group)
        G.add_edges_from([(group_name, elem) for elem in group])
    return G


def get_components_of_groups(groups):
    G = groups_to_graph(groups)
    return list(nx.connected_components(G))


components = get_components_of_groups(groups)
for component in components:
    print(component)
```

Output:

```
{'E', 'X', 'Z', 'Y', 'W', 'A', 'D', 'b3', 'B', 'C', 'b2', 'b1', 'b0'}
{'BB', 'CC', 'b4', 'AA'}
```

Speed: In order to compute the connected components of 1000 groups with 100 random elements each, it takes approximately 400 milliseconds. Believe it or not, most of the time is spent creating the graph. The connected component algorithm is comparatively fast.

Comment: In this example there should be 2 buckets {A, B, C, D, E, X, Y, Z, W} and {AA, BB, CC}. What are the other members inside? like b0, b1 etc? But amazing to think of it as graph

Comment: works perfectly also on large examples. thanks!

Comment: @Chris Those elements represent the groups which originally held those elements. The line `group_name = f"b{i}"` controls what name the group has. The first group, `['A', 'B', 'C']`, is group 0, so b0 is connected to A, B, and C. You can see that in the diagram.